# How to make specific parts of an equation large?

Tags: equations

I have the following equation in a document which doesn't look particularly neat once produced:

```
\begin{equation}
\nu = \frac{x_{max}^{sub}}{x_{min}^{host}},
\end{equation}
```

I need the \nu and both 'x' terms to be larger so there is a little more space for their sub/superscript notes to breathe. Additionally, the simpler the better, as I'll only be doing it once in the whole document and would rather not define any typeset for equations etc.

Thanks

Comment: Making those sub/super-scripts upright is a good start...is it sufficient?  `\nu = \frac{x_\text{max}^\text{sub}}{x_\text{min}^\text{host}}` (`amsmath` package required).

Comment: You can also uncramp the fraction, using `\nu = \frac{\displaystyle x_\text{max}^\text{sub}}{\displaystyle x_\text{min}^\text{host}}` which will add a little more vertical separation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: In a case like this, I’d rather go for `\mathrm{max}` and `\mathrm{sub}`.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{graphicx}` and then `\scalebox{1.5}{$\nu$}` to scale an item to 150% of it's current size.

Comment: @Werner: Well—no.  If you want to proceed along those lines, then I’d rather use `\mbox{\LARGE $\nu$}`, say.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the methods discussed in the comments, you could apply the super/sub-scripts to a `\strut`, which would apply added vertical separation, shown in the last example.

The first example is the OP's construct, the 2nd uses both `\mathrm` on the scripts, as well as "uncramping" the style with the use of `\displaystyle`.  The last case applies the scripts to a `\strut`.

I would recommend against trying to change the default size of `\nu` and `x` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\nu = \frac{x_{max}^{sub}}{x_{min}^{host}},
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
\nu = \frac{\displaystyle x_\mathrm{max}^\mathrm{sub}}{\displaystyle x_\mathrm{min}^\mathrm{host}},
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
\nu = \frac{x\strut_\mathrm{max}^\mathrm{sub}}{x\strut_\mathrm{min}^\mathrm{host}},
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

[image]